# NSFontSize actual size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I set the font size using NSFontSize(10,12,13...80)
But I wonder if there is detail info that describes the font size and related actual size(pixels/points)

I welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at UIFont-Documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

There are propertys like

```
pointSize
lineHeight
```

Comment: it is for nsfont rather than uifont